# Having issuses with getting a flash video to play

Tags: php, html, flash

I am building [a site](http://a-starpromotions.co.uk/sample/) with a flash video embeded on the home page now.

It works fine on my local server using WAMP.

But when I upload it it seems to lose the div that I have embeded the video in altogether.

I have never had this problem before when i have used swf. now im using a .flv

So I have no idea really unless I have forgot to upload somthing.

Comment: That link does load for me (in the US). Could you post any applicable code? Can you clarify if you are embedding an SWF that is playing an FLV, or are you trying to set the <object> tag directly to the FLV file?

Comment: Sorry the link was wrong should work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the path is correct relative to the html document's locations that the flash file resides on